# Rolling ball and number of generalized co-ordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, degrees-of-freedom

Consider a sphere constrained to roll on a rough surface.
Book says it requires 5 generalized co-ordinates to specify sphere's configuration: 2 for its centre of mass and 3 for its orientation.

I did not understand why 3 for orientation. I guess only 2 are needed: one  altitude and one azimuth i.e. $\theta$ and $\phi$. Since radius is fixed, $r$ is not needed.

So only 2+2 = 4 generalized co-ordinates are needed as per my (wrong) understanding.

Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you describe it, using $\theta$ and $\phi$ and $r$, you don't describe the orientation of the ball, you describe the position of a point on the ball, and for that you are right, you just need 2 coordinates to describe the position of a point on a sphere.

However, when it comes to the orientation (in what direction is each part of the sphere facing), then you really need 3 coordinates to describe that. Imagine you have a  little map of the earth on your ball, and you want to orientate the ball in a way so that the north-pole faces a certain direction. To do that, you need 2 degrees of freedom, because the north pole is just a point on the ball. However fixing the north pole into a certain direction, you still have the freedom to turn the ball arround the axis that goes exactly through its center, and through the northpole. And That is your third degree of freedom.

Comment: Suppose you fix a point P on the sphere and at this moment, it's co-ordinates are ($x_1$,$y_1$,$\theta_1$,$\phi_1$). You move the sphere by changing all these 4 coordinates by some amounts. Now P's new co-ordinates are ($x_2$,$y_2$,$\theta_2$,$\phi_2$). If you try move the sphere around the axis passing through P(with new co-ordinates ) and centre of the sphere (as you described), orientation of the sphere will change.

Comment: (in continuation with previous comment).............--Point P's co-ordinates will change (after rotation about the axis). Since sphere is rigid body, co-ordinates of the other remaining points on and inside sphere will also change-- i.e. orientation of the sphere has changed. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. But what you miss is: You can change orientation of the sphere, with $(x_1, y_1, \theta_1, \phi_1)$ staying the same. If you fix the point P, and you rotate the ball arround the described axis, which goes through the center, and through P, then you will change the orientation (because, as you said, the sphere is a rigid body, and all the other points will move). But you won't change any of the coordinates $(x_1, y_1, \theta_1, \phi_1)$ with this operation. That is why you need 3 degrees of freedom to describe orientation, not just 2, as you thought before.